# How to zoom to specific marker — osmdroid API (version 5.2@aar)

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Marker example:

```
            Marker m = new Marker(mapOSM);
            //m.setTitle("LOL");
            m.setSnippet("bla bla bla);
            m.setPosition(new GeoPoint(cenario.getLatitude(), cenario.getLongitude()));

            Drawable icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_action_place, null);
            icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_green_400), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

            m.setIcon(icon);

            mapOSM.getOverlays().add(m);
```

I know how to animate to a position:

`mapOSM.getController().animateTo(m.getPosition());`

But how to zoom to a specific marker??

Comment: What do you mean by zoom in on a specific marker? Just going one zoom level further after animating to a position?

Comment: Yes, as the CameraUpdateFactory does in Google Maps API, for example:
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(Constants.MAPS_DEFAULT_ZOOM).build();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly solution:

Do it

`mapOSM.getController().setZoom(10);`

And then do it

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapOSM.getController().animateTo(new GeoPoint(x, y));
        }
    }, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BoundingBoxE6 bBox = new BoundingBoxE6(iNorth, iEast, iSouth, iWest);

osmView.getController().zoomToSpan(bBox.getLatitudeSpanE6(), bBox.getLongitudeSpanE6());
osmView.getController().setCenter(bBox.getCenter());
```

Get a bounding box of where you want to go then zoom to a level that fits your Bbox and set your view's center as the center of the box.